# Use includes() instead of joins() with Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two Models `invoice` and `payevents`. The relationship between them is `invoice` has_many `payevents`.

I'm using the following query to get all bills that have been fully paid.:

```
Invoice.joins(:payevents).group("invoice.id").having("sum(payevents.amount) >= invoice.amount")
```

This query works fine. However, it is not optimal since the result doesn't include the `payevents`. I tried to use `includes` instead of `joins` but it doesn't work.

```
Invoice.includes(:payevents).group("invoice.id").having("sum(payevents.amount) >= invoice.amount")
```

The error is

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "payevents.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

I use PostgreSQL and Rails 4.1

Comment: I think you have explicity define which fields you need by `select('invoice.id, sum(payevents.amount)')`. Let me know if it works I write it as answer

Comment: Could you describe which fields you want in output? Difference between `includes` and `joins` is `includes` = `LEFT JOIN` and `joins` = `INNER JOIN`

Comment: I need all columns from Invoice and Payevents in the result to prevent hundreds of additional queries when looping through the original `joins` result in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The much simpler solution is to explicitly use preload

```
Invoice.joins(:payevents).group("invoice.id").having("sum(payevents.amount) >= invoice.amount").preload(:payevents)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand you - you should use subquery. Like this:

```
subquery = Invoice.joins(:payevents)
                  .group("invoice.id")
                  .having("sum(payevents.amount) >= invoice.amount")
                  .select("invoice.id id, sum(payevents.amount) amount").to_sql

query = Invoice.includes(:payevents).joins("JOIN (#{subquery}) subquery ON invoice.id = subquery.id")
```

So, you'll have Invoice, aggregated amount, filtered result by inner join of subquery and all payevents fields.

Comment: That works. However, `includes(:payevents)` has to be put before `joins`